# How do I exclude one of two packages with the same name using @ComponentScan?

Tags: java, spring, annotations

I have package one:

```
xxx.yyy.zzz {
 SampleClass1.java
}
```

and package two:

```
xxx.yyy.zzz {
 SampleClass2.java
}
```

and packaged three:

```
aaa.bbb.ccc {
 TopClass.java
}
```

From TopClass, I'm using component scan so that way I can load in the class from Package 2 because I want to @Autowire SampleClass2.java. However, using component scan, it tries to bring in SampleClass1.java since they have the same package name. When doing this, it causes a bunch of errors as SampleClass1, which I do not need, necessitates additional dependency beans to be satisfied.

How do I @Autowire SampleClass2.java without facing conflicts from SampleClass1.java?

Comment: The answer is correct : it does not matter if your source code has three different folders of the same name. When things are compiled, then there is only one package. There is no such thing two different packages having the same name. The name is the only defining attribute of a package.

Comment: I am wondering if the solution is to not import anything but to use fully qualified class names all over the place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I meant the package header was the same and this caused an issue:
IE at the top of the file:

```
package xxx.yyy.zzz;
```

I was able to solve the issue as such:

```
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses =
        {
                SampleClass2.class,
        },
        useDefaultFilters = false,
        includeFilters = {@ComponentScan.Filter(
                        type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE,
                        value = {
                                SampleClass2.class,
                        })
})
```

This type of component scan strictly took the necessary classes without taking in additional dependencies.

Answer (score 3):

From my understanding, there can not be two packages with the same name it would be the same package with two classes.
So your packages and classes are structured as such:

`xxx.yyy.zzz{
       SampleClass2.java,
       SampleClass1.java
     }`

Meaning when you use component scan on the package you will load both classes.
If this is the case then:

- I would recommend either separating them in a different package. or
- Remove `SampleClass1.java` as a component, however, this means you cannot Autowire `SampleClass1.java` where it's needed.